Derivative of matrix function involving matrix exponential
Suppose I want to compute $\frac{\text{d} (id-e^{iA}){A}^{-1}}{\text{d} x}$ for some $A = A(x)$.
Note that $(id-e^{iA}){A}^{-1}$ is defined by
$$
\frac{id-e^{iA}}{A} = -i\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{i^k}{(k+1)!} A^k
$$
Is it possible to use a similar product rule for the scalar valued function to find this derivative:
$$
\frac{\text{d} (id-e^{iA}){A}^{-1}}{\text{d} x}  = \frac{\text{d} (id-e^{iA})}{\text{d} x}{A}^{-1} + (id-e^{iA})\frac{\text{d} {A}^{-1}}{\text{d} x}
$$
where
$$
\frac{\text{d} {A}^{-1}}{\text{d} x} = -A^{-1}\frac{\text{d} {A}}{\text{d} x}A^{-1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\text{d} (id-e^{iA})}{\text{d} x} = - \frac{\text{d} e^{iA}}{\text{d} x}
$$
It can be found as a textbook result that contains adjoint representation of $A$.

Could you clarify this a little? Is $A(x)$ a matrix-valued function of a single variable $x$? If $A(x)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then is $id-\exp(iA)$ equal to $I_n -\exp(iA)$, where $I_n$ is the matrix with entries $\delta_{ij}$, that is $0$ if $i\neq j$ and $1$ if $i=j$?

Product rule for matrices follows from the ordinary product rule by just looking at the components.

Consider the function (and its derivative) for a scalar variable
$\,\lambda\in{\mathbb C}$
$$\eqalign{
\def\q{\quad} \def\qq{\qquad} \def\o{{\tt1}} \def\l{\lambda}
f(\l) = \frac{\o-e^{i\l}}{\l},\qq f'(\l)=\frac{(\o-i\l)\,e^{i\l}-\o}{\l^2} \\
}$$
Use the Eigenvalue Decomposition of $A=A(x)\,$ at a given value of $x$
$$\eqalign{
\def\L{L}
\def\M{M^{-1}}
A &= M\,\L\,\M \q\implies\q \L={\rm Diag}(\l_k) \\
}$$
and invoke the Daleckii-Krein Theorem to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\def\dA{\frac{dA}{dx}}
\def\dF{\frac{dF}{dx}}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\dAp{\LR{\dA}}
F &= f(A) \\\\
R_{jk} &= \begin{cases}
{\large\frac{f(\l_j)\,-\,f(\l_k)}{\l_j\,-\,\l_k}} \qq {\rm if\;}\l_j\ne\l_k \\
\\
\q f'(\l_k) \qq\q\;\,{\rm otherwise}\\
\end{cases} \\\\
\dF &= M\BR{R\odot\LR{\M\dAp M}} \M\\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

An alternative approach is to differentiate the power series of the function
$$\eqalign{
F &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kA^k \\
\dF &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \; \sum_{j=\o}^k A^{k-j}\dAp A^{j-\o} \\
}$$
In general, $\,\dA$ does not commute with $A$, so the second summation cannot be reduced.

Thanks a lot for this answer. I wonder whether there is a minor typo in the name "Dakeckii-Krein Theorem" since my search engine returns information with "Daleckii-Krein Theorem".

Oops! That was a typo.
